# List of tuples of dictionaries and ints, how to search through each dict

Tags: python

I'm working on a project in which I have a list that contains tuples of a dict and an int.  I'm trying to search through each dictionary for a give name but I'm having some trouble.

```
dicts = [ (somedict, 0), (someOtherDict, 5)]
```

Before I just had a list of dicts so I could easily search through with

```
def search(name):
    for d in reversed(dicts):
        if name in d: return d[name]
```

But now that I have a list of tuples I'm not quite sure how to search through the dictionaries.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  I'm so confused now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a generator expression to get your dicts:

```
def search(name):
    for d in (t[0] for t in dicts):
        if name in d: return d[name]
```

Alternatively you can use tuple assignment:

```
def search(name):
    for d, _ in dicts:
        if name in d: return d[name]
```

but that assumes that all your tuples have 2 values.

Comment: Is there also an easy way to add something to a given dictionary? Before I had to incorporate tuples I could use
    dictstack[-1][name] = value
But now that I'm in a list of tuples with dictionaries I'm a little lost.

Comment: `dictstack[-1][0][name] = value`, just one more level to add :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to index the results from enumerating dicts with 0 because that's where your dict is in the dict/int tuple.

```
def search(name):
    for d in reversed(dicts):
        if name in d[0]: return d[0][name]
```